# What causes a Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'ServiceWorkerGlobalScope': 'only-if-cached' can be set only with 'same-origin' mode error?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, fetch-api

After upgrading to Chrome 64, I realized that this error appears when I load my page on a new tab.

[image]

I can't identify where it is on the service worker. Here is my code to run the fetch:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
   if (event.request.url.startsWith(self.location.origin)) {
       event.respondWith(
           caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
              return response || fetch(event.request).then(function(fetch_resp){
                  return fetch_resp;
              });
           })
       );
   }
});
```

Could anyone here, who has more knowledge about service worker, help me to solve this error?

Comment: I'm looking into this a bit. In the meantime, any idea as to whether you see this error only when DevTools is open? I know that it's hard to figure that out, since you can't necessarily check for the error without opening DevTools... the reason I ask is that https://github.com/paulirish/caltrainschedule.io/pull/51/files sounds similar.

Comment: Here is [some documention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache), so it seems to be related to the *Request.cache* API.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I believe this is a Chromium bug that has been reported [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=823392). Hopefully it will be fixed soon or some more information about the issue will be published.

Paul Irish implemented a temporary work around, which is as follows:

```
if (e.request.cache === 'only-if-cached' && e.request.mode !== 'same-origin') {
  return;
}
```

I ran it inside the callback for the service worker `install` and `fetch` listeners and it prevented the error.

You can see the [full commit of Paul's code here](https://github.com/paulirish/caltrainschedule.io/pull/51/commits/82d03d9c4468681421321db571d978d6adea45a7).

Comment: Getting it on Outlook.com on Google Chrome, is this the same as Chromium?

Comment: @lllllllllllllIllllIll Chromium is the open-source project that the Chrome browser is based on. Chrome as a browser includes additional features and technologies that require licensing - Chromium does not include these things among other smaller differences.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)

Answer (score 0):

For those searching for this again, seems like it popped up after a while again when someone opens the devtools you can still see the error mentioned in the question.

See (new) bug report here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1098389

So let's hope this will be fixed again soon!

Answer (score -1):

perhaps the cache name is not unique from other applications, seems to fix the issue for me.