# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'ServiceWorkerGlobalScope': 'only-if-cached' can be set only with 'same-origin' mode

Tags: javascript, django, browser-cache, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I getting this error in my Service Worker. I have a page that changes dynamically with user usage. I do not want to cache my requests. Can someone help me to change my `fetch` event but still allow me to have a [progressive webapp](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/)?

**sw.js**

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
'use strict';

this.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open('myapp-v1.0.0.2').then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll([
        "/",
      ]);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  var body_content = JSON.parse(event.data.text());
  var title = body_content.title;
  var options = {
    body: body_content.text,
    icon: body_content.icon,
    badge: body_content.icon,
    data: {
      url: body_content.url
    }
  };

  event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  event.notification.close();
  event.waitUntil(
    clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.url)
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
  // or simply don't call event.respondWith, which
  // will result in default browser behaviour
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.filter(function(cacheName) {
          // Return true if you want to remove this cache,
          // but remember that caches are shared across
          // the whole origin
        }).map(function(cacheName) {
          return caches.delete(cacheName);
        })
      );
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: Remove the comma in the " return cache.addAll([  "/" ]) " and try

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48463483

Comment: @HarishKarthick trailing commas [are valid in ES5 and have wide browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas), so that's not it.