# Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'ServiceWorkerGlobalScope': 'only-if-cached' can be set only with 'same-origin' mode

Tags: fetch, service-worker

**Do you know how to solve this error?**

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
console.log('[Service Worker] Fetching something ...', event);
event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
```

});

Comment: Post questions in question section not as an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'ServiceWorkerGlobalScope': 'only-if-cached' can be set only with 'same-origin' mode error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48463483/what-causes-a-failed-to-execute-fetch-on-serviceworkerglobalscope-only-if)