# Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'WorkerGlobalScope'

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I trying to fetch data from the server inside of a web worker. But in dev tools every time I got the same error.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': Failed to parse URL from /api/books
```

I saw  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48463483/what-causes-a-failed-to-execute-fetch-on-serviceworkerglobalscope-only-if) answer about service workers, but it's not working for me.

WebWorker file code!

```
// data-handling.web-worker.js

const workercode = () => {
  onmessage = async e => {
    const res = await fetch('/api/books');

    postMessage(res);
  }
};

let code = workercode.toString();
code = code.substring(code.indexOf('{')+1, code.lastIndexOf('}'));

const blob = new Blob([code], {type: 'application/javascript'});
const worker_script = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

export default worker_script;
```

Imported in React component.

```
import data_handling_worker from "./data-handling.web-worker";
const dataHandlingWorker = new Worker(data_handling_worker);
```

Running and posting messages inside of the hooks!

```
const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');
const [booksList, setBooksList] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  dataHandlingWorker.postMessage(searchQuery);
}, [searchQuery]);

useEffect(() => {
  dataHandlingWorker.onmessage = (m) => {
    setBooksList(m.data);
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: The question you linked doesn't seem to have anything to do with your "*Failed to parse URL*" error?

Comment: Try using an absolute URL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Workers created from a `blob://` URI have their [`baseURI` set to set to that `blob://` URI](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#worker-processing-model:concept-workerglobalscope-url).

To fetch a relative URL the browser first has to build an absolute URI from the current realm's `baseURI`.

So in your case, the browser will try to generate an absolute URL from `/api/books` using `blob:[origin]/[UUID]` as the base. **This is what throws**:

```js
const worker_script = `
  postMessage( { baseURI: self.location.href } );
  try {
    const absolute = new URL( "api/books", self.location.href );
  }
  catch( err ) {
    postMessage( { err: err.toString() } );
  }
`;
const worker_url = URL.createObjectURL( new Blob( [ worker_script ] ) );
const worker = new Worker( worker_url );
worker.onmessage = (evt) => console.log( evt.data );
```

To workaround that issue you have two options:

- Use an absolute URL. This way you won't face that problem.
- Pass the `baseURI` from your main thread to your Worker's script. This way you will be able to create the absolute URL yourself using the [URL constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL).

The first option is really simple, so I guess you don't need an example.
For the second, since we can't host relative files in StackSnippets, [I had to host it in this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QsQ7EQKI2tzEdFIO?preview).

Here is the code:

```js
const worker_script = `
  onmessage = (evt) => {
    const base = evt.data;
    const absolute = new URL( "api/books", base );
    fetch( absolute )
      .then( (resp) => resp.text() )
      .then( (txt) => postMessage( txt ) )
      .catch( console.error );
  };
`;
const worker_url = URL.createObjectURL( new Blob( [ worker_script ] ) );
const worker = new Worker( worker_url );
worker.onmessage = (evt) => document.body.append( evt.data );
// pass the main thread's baseURI
worker.postMessage( document.baseURI );
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I wanted to make a conditional response depending on the cache.

[image]

I was using the request object and paying attention to this post and using the absolute url solved the problem.

```
const respuesta = caches.match('codeGalery/cat.jpg')
.then((response) => 
{
  if (response !== undefined)
  {
    return response;
  }
  //wrong
  //return fetch(FetchEvent.request, {credentials:"same-origin"});
  //correct
  return fetch(FetchEvent.request.url, {credentials:"same-origin"});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const worker_script = `
  postMessage( { baseURI: self.location.href } );
  try {
    const absolute = new URL( "api/books", self.location.href );
  }
  catch( err ) {
    postMessage( { err: err.toString() } );
  }
`;
const worker_url = URL.createObjectURL( new Blob( [ worker_script ] ) );
const worker = new Worker( worker_url );
worker.onmessage = (evt) => console.log( evt.data );
```

Comment: Greetings, welcome to SO. Please avoid 'code-only' answers as they do not provide insight as to why something works. Explain why your code fixes X problem. Perhaps read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) by the SO team.