# Fetch from web worker does not send (same) Origin

Tags: javascript, web, cors, fetch, web-worker

I'm trying to create a web worker that stores the access token and handles API calls. The first thing I want to do is a get request from the web worker to get the access token.

The user uses cookies; httpOnly and SameSite are on, secure not yet because I'm running it locally on http. This cookies is where the tokens or identities of the tokens are stored.

I have an endpoint in my api, which I want to address to obtain the access token. I can then address the required resources with this. Token stays in the web worker and is not exposed.

I have a web worker (in base64 string) from that web worker I want to reach the endpoint to get the access token. I do this with fetch. However, when I want to send credentials. The CORS can not be set to '*'. I can specify the url of my website (in this case localhost) as origin in the server.

Within my web worker:

```
const tryFetch = await fetch(authUrl, {
  credentials: "include",
});
```

However, it seems that the origin passed to the server is 'null'. Is there a way to fix this or am I trying something wrong?

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:3000' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Comment: See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42242802/441757. Not sure what you mean by _“I have a web worker (in base64 string)”_ but I’m guessing that’s what’s causing the browser to set the origin to null.

Comment: I was pretty confident there were already an exact dupe but I can't find it anymore... If someone finds it and doesn't have a dupe-hammer, let me know please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`data:` URLs for Workers are considered opaque origins ([specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#script-settings-for-workers:concept-origin-opaque)). This means that the origin of your Worker will be set to `null`.

To circumvent that if you really need to create your Worker script dynamically (instead of using a static file), then you can use a `blob:` URL, which will share the origin of the context where the URL has been created.

```js
const content = `
  // your worker script content
`;
const getWorkerURL = () => {
  return URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([content], {type: "text/javascript"}));
};
const worker = new Worker(getWorkerURL());
```

[Live example as a codepen](https://codepen.io/_-0-_/pen/BaYyRXx), because StackSnippets iframes are null origined anyway.

However beware that even though the Worker does share the same origin, its `baseURI` will be different, so you need to [special handle relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60842121/3702797).