# Lighthouse PWA Audit fail "does not register a service worker that controls page and start_url"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, lighthouse

I am getting the above failure in my lighthouse audit. Having looked through SO and [here](https://web.dev/service-worker/) it "should" be working.

There are no errors in the console.

This is the Manifest: -

```
{
"short_name": "Brotkrumen",
"name": "Brotkrumen Web App",
"description": "Native Background Geolocation POC",
"icons": [
{
  "src": "gingerbreadhouse.png",
  "sizes": "48x48 128x128 144x144 192x192 512x512",
  "type": "image/png"
}
],
"start_url": "/TravelManager.html",
"background_color": "#00ccdd",
"theme_color": "#00ccdd",
"display": "fullscreen"
 }
```

This is the ServiceWorker code: -

```
'use strict';
 /* identification division.
  * program-id.    echo.
  * author.        Richard Maher.
  */

var   doryRegister  = [];            // Meet someone new every day.
const INTRO         = "GrussGott";   // Tell clients we're new.
const FLEET_MANAGER = "/Fleet/Move"; // Starship control.
const CACHE_NAME    = "BrotkrumenV1.0"
    
self.addEventListener('install',
function (e) {
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function (cache) {
            return cache.addAll([
                '/TravelManager.html',
                '/hg.png',
                '/gingerbreadhouse.png',
                '/striped-witch-hat.png',
                '/brotkrumen.css',
                '/echo.js',
                '/registerserviceworker.js',
                '/brotkrumen.json',
                '/TravelManagerPolyfill.js',
                '/HandleMap.js'
            ]).then(() => self.skipWaiting());
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(e) 
{
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then((keyList) => {
            return Promise.all(keyList.map((key) => {
                if (key !== CACHE_NAME) {
                    console.log('Removing cache', key);
                    return caches.delete(key);
                }
            }));
        })
    );

    e.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (e) {

    console.log(e.request.url);
    if (e.request.url.startsWith(self.location.origin)) {
        e.respondWith(

            caches.match(e.request).then(function (response) {
                console.log("Request " + e.request.url);
                if (response) {
                    console.log("Response " + response.url);
                    if (e.request.cache === 'only-if-cached') {
                        e.request.mode = 'same-origin'
                    }
                } else
                    console.log("No MATCH");

                return response || fetch(e.request);

            })

        );
    }
    return fetch(e.request);
});
```

The register service worker code: -

```
'use strict';
/* identification division.
 * program-id.    RegisterServiceWorker.
 * author.        Richard Maher.
 * version.       1.0
 */

function registerServiceWorker()
{   
// Make sure SW is there
navigator.serviceWorker.register('echo.js', {scope: './'})
    .then(reg => {
            window.addEventListener("unload",unsubscribeTravelManager);
            console.log('SW Registered');
        })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('SW Registration failed with ' + err);
        reportError({header:"Could not register ServiceWorker",
                    message:err});
        return;
    });
  
// Register for Background Geolocation tracking. Take default for accuracy, max age.    
navigator.serviceWorker.ready
    .then(reg => {
        reg.travelManager.subscribe({
                            minSilence:     5, // Car trip value. Collapse GPS.
                            maxSilence:   600, // Sanity check. Squelch off.
                            minProgress:   50, // Indoor accuracy an issue.
                            maxSnail:      55, // Brisk walk.
                            dropDodgy:   true  // Avoid wireless Pong.
                            })
            .then(subscription => {travelSubscription = subscription}, locFail)
            .catch(err => {
                    console.log('Travel Manager Subscription failed with ' + err);
                    reportError({header:"Could not subscribe to Travel Manager",
                            message:err});
            });
    });
}

function unsubscribeTravelManager(e)
{   
// Tidy up
const CANCEL   = true;
var   shutdown = Promise.resolve(false);

if (travelSubscription) 
    shutdown = travelSubscription.unsubscribe(CANCEL);
    
shutdown
    .then(success => {
            console.log("Unsubscribed from TravelManager = " + success);
            navigator.serviceWorker.ready
                .then(reg => {
                        reg.unregister()
                        .then(success => {console.log('SW Unregistered = ' + success)})         
                        })          
        })
    .catch(err => console.log("Couldn't unregister SW " + err))
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
"start_url": "/TravelManager.html"
```

with

```
"start_url": "."
```

Comment: Now I get a faile on the fetch: - only-if-cached' can be set only with 'same-origin' mode

Comment: I put in the workaround suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48463483/what-causes-a-failed-to-execute-fetch-on-serviceworkerglobalscope-only-if and now still get the original error

Answer (score 0):

Pilot error :-(

In the page unload event when I unsubscribed from the TravelManager I also unregistered the ServiceWorker which sort of defeated the purpose. My bad.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is with your service worker. I haven't found any code where you've registered your service worker at a specific URL.

```js
const serviceWorkerUrl = '/sw.js';

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceWorkerUrl).then(function(registration) {
      // Registration was successful
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }, function(err) {
      // registration failed :(
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
  });
}
```

You should register your service worker before you add event listener for `install`, `activate` & `fetch`. Please follow this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers#register_a_service_worker) if you want to learn more about it.

Comment: I've added the SW registration code in the OP. The TravelManager is added via ServiceWorkerRegistration.prototype.travelManager 
  = new BackgroundGeolocation();
The TravelManagerPolyfill code et al can be found here https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen

Comment: I changed the registration scope to  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/echo.js')    and still no joy :-(
When the page and SW first loads I still get: - 'only-if-cached' can be set only with 'same-origin' mode